# Backbone save nested collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have **model** like this:

```
defaults:{
    id:'',
    name: '',
    type: new typeCollection()
},
parse: function(response){
    var self = this;
    var typeCol = typeCollection;
    typeCol.fetch({ data: $.param({ id: response.id}),
        success: function (collection, response) {
            self.set('type', response);
        }}
    });
    return response; 
...

  console.log(model.attribute)
//{"id":"7","name":"myName","type":[{"tid": "2","tName": "myTName"},{"tid": "3","tName": "mOTName"}]}
```

**View**:

```
Marionette.ItemView.extend({        
    template: _.template(myTpl),

    initialize: function(options){
        this.model = options.model;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render); 
    },      

    events:{
        "click #saveChanges":"saveIt"
    },      

    saveIt: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = this.$('#basic_info');
        var arr = form.serializeArray();
        var data = _(arr).reduce(function(acc, field) {

          acc[field.name] = field.value;
          return acc;
        }, {});         
        this.model.save(data);
console.log(data)//{"id":"7","name":"yourName","tName[0]": "myTName","tName[1]": "mOTName"}
```

**Template:** UPDATE: added index to tName

```
<form id="basic_info">
    <input name="myName" value="<%= myName%>" type="text">

      <% _.each(type, function(item, index) { %> 
    <input name="tName[index]" value="<%= item.tName %>" type="text">
      <% }); %>
</form>
```

This works, it fulfils inputs fields. But I am not able to update (save()) nested "type" collection. How can I proper update nested collection and not lose "connection" to his parent model?

Thanks to your answer and comments I make it works, I had to change template and the way how I grab data from the form.

Here is **solution**:

Template:

```
<% _.each(type, function(item) { %>
   <div  data-nested="true" data-item-id="<%= item.tid %>" >
     <input  name="itemName" value="<%= item.tName %>" type="text">
   </div>
<% }); %>
```

View:

```
//serialize only static part of the form
var rootInfo = _.object(_.map($('.serialize :input').serializeArray(), _.values))

var type= [];   

form.find('div[data-nested=true]').each(function(){
var self = $(this);     
  var tid    = self.data('item-id');
  var tName= self.find('input[name=itemName]').val();

     type.push({'tid'   :tid,
                'tName':tName })
 })

//merge basic info with type
_.extend(rootInfo , {type:type}) 

this.model.save(rootInfo);
```

Comment: please show data before this.model.save(data);

Comment: I added data output, please see "View".

Comment: is it expected that all models share the same collection? if not then you should not provide a new Collection in the defaults as this will be shared across all models

Comment: in most cases this model will have this collection (set of additional info fields). Anyway, if not it will be just an empty array?

Comment: I'd guess that's because Backbone uses _.isEqual to see if model attributes have changed. It just does a simple comparison, which completely fails complex objects (arrays, objects, Models, Collections).  You may have to override the changedAttributes on your model to append 'type' if any of the collections's models have changed attributes of their own.

Comment: is problem in send to server/ not in getting from form?

Answer (score 2):

Form can have only one field with name tName / tid so try to change your template for example as

```
<form id="basic_info">
    <input name="myName" value="<%= myName%>" type="text">

      <% _.each(type, function(item) { %> 
    <input name="tName[]" value="<%= item.tName %>" type="text">
      <% }); %>
</form>
```

then you've got ability to get all data and manipulate with it before save

you'll get an array of fields in formData, so you need to set needed fields as array to model field. If you need code example - please create test from at jsbin at give the link - community will add code

Comment: it doesn't work. but I tried another option `<%_.each(type,function(item, index) { %>` then `name="tName[index]"`, this work but it will not update model (nested collection)

Comment: @InTry as @Vasil says - `set the nested fields to model's field.` Model should look like : `{id:1, name: 'xyz', type: ['val1', 'val2']}`